# Pegando Valores de um intervalo de numeros onde as dezenas n se repetem

Tags: java

Gostaria de um caminho para resolução de um problema que consiste em ler 2 números do usuário que serão meu inicio e fim ex 10 e 50 e dentro desse intervalo não mostrar os números repetidos ex 11,22,33,44.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia transformar esse `int` para `String` e assim comparar sua substring ou ainda usar uma expressão regular

Algo parecido com isso:

```java
int inicio = 0;
int fim = 50;

for (int i = inicio; i < fim; i++) {
  String check = String.valueOf(i);
  if (check.length() > 1) {
    if (check.substring(0, 1).equals(check.substring(1, 2))) {
      System.out.println(i); //mostro os repetidos
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Problema: e quando o valor final for superior a 100? Ao verificar o valor 115, por exemplo, sua condição será verdadeira. De forma genérica, como faria para trabalhar com string sem saber o número de dígitos dos valores?

Comment: Como exemplo peguei os valores mostrados já que a pergunta diz: **problema que consiste em ler 2 números**, mas se a entrada é outra talvez teria que usar um regex ao invés da substring: `if(check.matches("^(\\d)\\1+$")){}`

Comment: Veja que a pergunta não limita o intervalos possíveis, então busque incrementar sua resposta com uma solução mais genérica.

Comment: Obrigado brother.